# How to use App.Xaml's ResourseDictionaries with own entry point

Tags: c#, wpf, app.xaml

I created some logic for singleInstance application and I must to use my own entry point (not App.xaml) for Application.  I have some styles in App.xaml which now is not working. How can I use this ResourceDictionaries from my App.xaml for entire project in my situation?

My class for manage Application Startup

```
 public class SingleInstanceManager : WindowsFormsApplicationBase
{
    App app;

    public SingleInstanceManager()
    {
        this.IsSingleInstance = true;
    }

    protected override bool OnStartup(Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // First time app is launched
            app = new App();
            App.Current.Properties["rcID"] = e.CommandLine;
            //IntroLibrary.OpenDocumentFromNotify();
            app.Run();
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStartupNextInstance(StartupNextInstanceEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        // Subsequent launches
        base.OnStartupNextInstance(eventArgs);
        Intro win = (Intro)app.MainWindow;
        if (eventArgs != null)
        {
            App.Current.Properties["rcID"] = eventArgs.CommandLine[0];
        }
        IntroLibrary.OpenDocumentFromNotify();
        app.Activate();
    }
}
```

and my own Entry Point:

```
    public class EntryPoint
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SingleInstanceManager manager = new SingleInstanceManager();
        manager.Run(args);
    }
}
```

And my App.Xaml code behind:

```
    public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        // Create and show the application's main window
        Intro window = new Intro();
        window.Show();
    }

    public void Activate()
    {
        // Reactivate application's main window
        this.MainWindow.Activate();
    }
}
```

And my App.xaml has some code which decribe ResourceDictionaries which doesnt work. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution for this problem. I create new Resource Dictionary and paste all my other Resourse in this new dictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
 <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="themes/ShinyBlue.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="themes/Anim.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="themes/Generic.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="themes/CustomStyles.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="themes/Resource.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="themes/CustomWindowChrome.xaml" />
 </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

and then just edited a little bit my App.cs

```
   public partial class App : Application
{

    protected override void OnStartup(System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        ResourceDictionary rd = new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("CommonStyle.xaml",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) };
        this.Resources = rd;
        // Create and show the application's main window
        Intro window = new Intro();
        window.Show();
    }

    public void Activate()
    {
        // Reactivate application's main window
        this.MainWindow.Activate();
    }
}
```

I hope this solution help somebody )))

Comment: If you want the IDE to use the styles defined here in the editor, you can add a reference to the main resource dictionary in the App.xaml.  However, the application will still make the assignment using the code-behind